# RoboCopy slower than Xcopy? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy, xcopy

I'd been using xcopy in a backup script but every so often xcopy would fail with "*insufficient memory*" when a pathname would sneak into the backup set that exceeded 254 characters. Lots of advice on the web said xcopy was deprecated for robocopy and suggested using robocopy instead.

I switched to robocopy and it works fine but runs dramatically slower. These are big backup sets and the xcopy version ran for 6 hours, which was OK for overnight. But the robocopy version runs for 11 hours which means it's still running the next morning! Is there a way to speed up robocopy OR is there a way to force xcopy to ignore long file names and keep going? Here's sample code, old and new:

**xcopy S:\SharedFiles E:\NAS\SharedFiles /c /f /i /s /e /k /r /h /y /d /j 1>> C:\utilities\alloutput.txt 2>&1**

**robocopy S:\SharedFiles E:\NAS\SharedFiles /e /j /np /fp /r:1 /w:1 1>> C:\utilities\alloutput.txt 2>&1**

**N.B.** that I'm using the /C option in xcopy but that doesn't seem to stop xcopy from ending as soon as it encounters the long pathname.

**EDIT** I updated my script to do **/r:1 /w:1**. In my test run there were 78 errors requiring retries. This made a slight improvement but it's still way slower than the xcopy version. I've also tried it with and without **/J**, with no discernible improvement. I have not tried setting a threading limit, but AFAIK xcopy is single-threaded anyway and robocopy defaults to 8.

Comment: Since you aren't getting any hits, I can tell you what I think.  I have never had this issue and am not willing to fish through the 100 robocopy flags to figure out what you are doing wrong.  Chances are, your problems are with the flags you are invoking robocopy with.

Comment: @ Steve Rindsberg  Yes.  The target directory is a freshly-formatted USB external drive.  So nothing exists on the target device.   And this is exactly the same as the XCopy version I was using before.    Also, see my recent edit.

Comment: The multithreading in robocopy can dramatically bog down some storage like slow hdds. Try with `/mt:1` or `2` and see if the speed goes up. (or, try the opposite at `/mt:16`). I would remove `/j` unless your average file size is in GBs. Also remove `/np` and/or add `/eta` while you're troubleshooting to get an idea of the speeds compared to xcopy

Comment: I've now run over a week of these with different options.  Consistently the RoboCopy versions run slower.   Using /J versus not using it made no difference.   Various /mt settings didn't matter - in Task Manager it was seldom using more than 1 thread even though I'm running on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU, on Windows 10.   When the backup target was an SSD it was faster than when it was a hard-drive, but that was true for XCOPY as well.   So I'm at a loss for ideas.   I'll put this up for a bounty.

Comment: The results in [Robocopy vs. XCopy File Copy Performance](https://www.flexense.com/robocopy_vs_xcopy_file_copy_performance.html) are much more detailed as regarding performance factors, and there Robocopy achieved better results in 10 out of 18 tests. Your single test apparently is one of the cases where xcopy is better.

Comment: Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2255 CPU, 64G RAM, 1TB SSD, Windows 10.  The source of the backups (the data being backed up) lives on the PC and on a Synology DS212 RAID1 NAS with 500GB disk drives across a gigabit Ethernet connection.   The total size of the backup set from these two sources is 781 GB as of last night.  The target backup devices are a stack 1TB USB drives, some HD some SSD.   XCOPY is faster on all devices.

Comment: @harrymc but a typical backup operation requires doing many if not most of the things on that list so it should all average out.  And anyway I'm seeing musch bigger deltas between XCopy and Robocopy.   Based on those, common sense says that because I've never used Robocopy before it's something wrong that **I'm** doing so I'm trying to find out what.

Comment: Useful parameters might be `/nooffload` and `/FFT` and to use UNC path-names. `/256` might help in ignoring long names (conflicts with UNC). Network advice: You could [Disable TCP offloading and RSS settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/sql-server-ec2-best-practices/tcp-rss.html) on both sides of the network connection(s). Note: Both RoboCopy and Xcopy are ancient utilities. The fastest I ever found was [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/).

Comment: wondering if using the `/log` switch is a better option than piping. It is plausible that using a pipe can cause blocking if the buffer fills (or other magic). Additionally, the log file is presumably very large. Might be worth not logging for one run to see if there is an impact on execution time

Comment: @user316117 does the CPU on the NAS max out during robocopy runs? Have you already verified xcopy is actually copying the same list of files? For example, robocopy will follow junctions to copy their content as well, while xcopy will choke.

Comment: Also take a quick look at task manager, and add what your network usage is during xcopy/robocopy runs (they should be nearly the same). Try copying a single folder or something instead of waiting for hours

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Robocopy will be the faster alternative [in most cases](https://www.flexense.com/robocopy_vs_xcopy_file_copy_performance.html) however the most significant difference is that robocopy has a retry option where as xcopy does not retry on errors.

To verify this use the switch `r:0` instead of `r:1` (and `w:0` to be safe but that shouldn't make any difference).

Other than that I know of the following [performance switches](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

```
     /COMPRESS : Request SMB network compression during file transfer, if applicable.
            /J : Copy using unbuffered I/O (recommended for large files).
    /NOOFFLOAD : Copy files without using the Windows Copy Offload mechanism.
        /IPG:n : Inter-Packet Gap (ms), to free bandwidth on slow lines.
       /MT[:n] : Multithreaded copying, n = no. of threads to use (1-128)
                 default = 8 threads, not compatible with /IPG and /EFSRAW
                 Redirecting output using /LOG is recommended for even better performance.
```

Depending on your specific scenario it's helpful to specifically turn them off/on (in your case - does using `/j` actually make a difference?).

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about my previous answer, in which I experienced different results in output and execution times when adding the /MT flag, I started thinking that maybe your robocopy OUTPUT might be the culprit here.

I tested these 2 robocopy commands:

```
robocopy vbs vbs2 /e /j /np /fp /r:1 /w:1 1>> alloutput2.txt 2>&1

robocopy vbs vbs2 /e /j /np /fp /NC /NS /MT:16 /r:1 /w:1 1>> alloutput.txt 2>&1
```

The execution time for the first command was ~9 seconds, for copying 12k files of total size 660MB.
The execution time for the second command was ~2.7 seconds.

The output is a bit different as well.
The first command will output this:

```
New File            3056    C:\git\vbs\.editorconfig
```

The second will only output the filename:

```
        C:\git\vbs\.editorconfig
```

I suggest you try it, and increase the MT to 16, as your CPU could use it.